# jq How to pass key starting with numeral as argument

Tags: bash, jq

I'm trying to read a list of paths into `jq` for processing, like so:

```
# example path: bigFolder.smallFolder.file
for i in ${!paths[@]}; do 
    path="${paths[$i]}"
    # making sure jq recognizes argument as path
    keyPath=".$path"
    result=`echo "$path" | jq "$keyPath"
    ...
done
```

However, this process fails to read keys that start with numerals, like

```
bigFolder.smallFolder.1thing
bigFolder.smallFolder.2things
...

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

How can I make sure `jq` can properly read these path names in ?

Comment: You need to put quotes around it: `bigFolder.smallFolder."1thing"`

Comment: Also, `"$keyPath"` not `'$keyPath'` if you want the shell to replace the string `$keyPath` with the contents of the variable before starting jq.